# ¿Como correr varias veces un hilo en c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

¿por que me produce una excepción?

```
Thread hs;
hs = new Thread(()=>Playsound(sound));


while (bstate==-1)
{
    t = Int16.Parse(bpm.Text);
    t = 60000 / t;

    hs.Start();

    cajas[compas-1].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    cajas[0].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    await Task.Delay(t);

    for (int k = 1; k < compas-1; k++)
    {


        hs.Start();
        cajas[k-1].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        cajas[k].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        await Task.Delay(t);
    }

    hs.Start();

    cajas[compas - 2].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    cajas[compas - 1].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    await Task.Delay(t);

}
```

Texto de la excepción:

> System.Threading.ThreadStateException: 'Subproceso en ejecución o terminado; no se puede reiniciar.' La excepcion se produce en el segundo hs.Start();

Comment: Hola. Puedes indicarnos el mensaje de la excepción?

Comment: System.Threading.ThreadStateException: 'Subproceso en ejecución o terminado; no se puede reiniciar.'
 La excepcion se produce en el segundo hs.Start();

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas hilos en este caso? ¿Y por que tienes `await Task.Delay(t)` en diferentes lugares? Hay algo raro en el diseño.

Comment: estoy haciendo un metronomo, por eso es que ocupo {await Task.Delay(t)} dode 't', es el tipo que ponga el usuario, y quiero correr hilos por que se va descuadrando poco a poco, espero que si ocupo hilos para el sonido que reproduce sea mas exacto

Answer (score 1):

El error te explica exactamente lo que pasa. Un `thread` que ha finalizado no se puede volver a utilizar, algo que se explica en la documentación de [Thread.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6x4c42hc(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Once the thread terminates, it cannot be restarted with another call to Start.

O sea

> Una vez el thread finaliza, no puede ser reiniciado con otra llamada a Start.

La solución pasaría por volver a crear una instancia del thread (hacer `hs = new Thread(()=>Playsound(sound));` antes de cada `hs.Start()`); o tal vez usar ThreadPool.

De todas maneras, no me cansaré nunca de recomendar **no utilizar la clase Thread**. Es una clase antigua y muy difícil de usar correctamente, y .Net proporciona sustitutos mucho mas adecuados, modernos y sencillos: [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) y [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx).